# Strange wireless speed variation in terms of distance

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

For some time I noticed that my ultrabook Lenovo Thinkpad experiences a faster decrease in speed, in terms of distance from the router, as other devices. I tested (with speedtest.net) and these are the results (the following values are the approximated averages of download and upload speeds (download ~= upload anyways); also I didn't repeat the tests many times and they might not be accurate, but the problem is persistent!).

```
 Device           |      2 meters      | 4 meters + 1 wall  | 8 meters + 2 walls 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Lenovo Thinkpad  |      50 Mbps       |      30 Mbps       |      1.5 Mbps
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sony Xperia phone|      35 Mbps       |      30 Mbps       |       25 Mbps
```

Note that on a mid-range HP laptop the speed tends to vary in the phone's fashion (I can't make the tests on it right now; that is based purely on observation). When i download something being 8 meters away on the troubling device, it seems like every centimeter counts! Let's say I download something with 200kb/s, if I move 20 centimeters closer in the router's direction, the speed might go up to 300kb/s or even more! What might be the problem? Is the problem on the router's side (a mid-range TP-LINK) or is it on the laptop's side (hardware or software)? Can I fix it? (it bothers me when I try to watch videos) If not, I am quite curious what causes the problem anyways, because as far as I know, this is really, really strange!

Note: The ping is always about the same, including in the 8 meters case! (That is expected, nothing strange there)

Edit: Based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/556874/does-distance-from-the-router-affect-internet-speed) the speed shouldn't vary at all because Windows says that, at 8 meters, the wireless speed is 54-58 Mbps (down from 120 or so near the router). This should mean that I can use about the same speed as I do near the router, but that's not true at all!

Comment: What protocol is each using?  b,g,n,ac?  thats most of the modern protocols, and each has characteristics and limitations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11

Comment: Also turning the laptop or router 45, 90, or 135 degrees may drastically change the outcome. due to antennae orientation.

Comment: Well, the router's settings says: "11bgn mixed" if that's what you mean :) I didn't noticed too much of a diffrence when i turn any of the devices! (not to justify the massive drop in speed)

Comment: That is what the router is capable of providing, each connection to a device might be differnt.  Say the phone uses N mode while the laptop is G (or vice versa)

Comment: Laptop uses 802.11n (dunno about the phone, I might come back with an edit)

Comment: I will submit an answer once you come back.  What type of material is the wall made out of?  What frequencies are you using 5.0 GHz or 2.4 GHz on each device.  Without this information I cannot submit a quality answer.

Comment: I guess the frequency is 2.4GHz(not sure) and the walls are from concrete (old apartment)!

Comment: I've read all the comments up to this point, both here and attached to answers, basically after googling your router model number we know it's a 2.4 ghz b/g/n router.  If you check u will find out b is the oldest protocol and n is the newest and fastest.  In the real world your not experiencing anything that's surprising.   For example, I have 3 devices and in the same space right next to each other they will all get different results... Mostly it's about antennae type and orientation in the device, and whether the device was built for wireless speed or to optimize device battery life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to know for sure unless we know the exact model of the clients, but I'd be willing to put money on the problem being that the Lenovo device has only 1 antenna, and thus 1 data rate, while the Xperia device has more then 1 antenna and can handle MIMO.

[MIMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIMO) allows the recovery of reflected signals, something which will be more apparent the further away and the more obstacles that are in place.

It will be quite difficult to fix the problem on your Laptop - you may be able to get better performance with a more sensitive WIFI card, however you may still be limited to a single antenna.

Another possibility is that you are in a "noisy" area - ie lots of competing devices - and your Xperia device is not as good at detecting signals - thus it does not hear the further-away signals from other devices, while the Laptop does.  I guess you can test this theory by (a) Seeing if changing channels makes a difference, and (b) if the performance difference between the 2 devices varies substantially at quiet times - eg in the middle of the night.    If this theory proves correct, you can fix the problem by better shielding your home from external wireless signals - but this may not be feasible or desireable.

Comment: How to find if the laptop has MIMO or not? It's a Lenovo Thinkpad Helix if that helps you :D I kinda doubt it doesn't tho (i had older laptops that worked well. It would be quite strange if this has a worse Wifi card) And, well, no, I am not in a busy area. The laptop sees about 3-4 other WiFi's (along mine) while the phone sees about 2-3 other WiFi's (you're right, phone got it worse, but I don't think this is a big difference) The signal is about the same no matter the time of the day. What do you think? :)

Comment: We need exact model nos to help with this - or you can look up the driver and chipset in your OS.  You may also want to run wifi analyser on your cellphone to see if the frequencies overlap and their attenuation.  Lastly, the correct wifi firmware/driver can make a huge difference. Have you tried updati g these?

Comment: Signal being same does not neccessarily make a huge difference, its the amount of transmission being used on the band (and nearby bands as well). Also, number of bars/stars is highly subjective and may not be very meaningfull.   Also, newer devices are not always better then older ones, particularly with respect of antennas and snr.

Comment: Well, it seems complicated. I guess I need to learn a bit more about this stuff. I though it's something simple(er) :) It's not the end of the world it I can't quick fix. Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of undefined variables here, but the most likely culprit is in the wireless adapter types.

If your devices are using a mix of 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac technologies or 2.4/5GHz bands then they will exhibit different performance characteristics.

Also, many modern/high-end devices will have multiple antennas (diversity or MIMO) which will also change their performance.

Comment: My router has 3 antennas (I guess one for b, one for g and one for n; it's working on a 11bgn mixed mode). The laptop is connected with the n protocol and, at 8 meters distance Windows says the bandwidth should be up to   58 or so!

Comment: @Caution - You would be mistaken about the antennas and the 802.11 aspect of your comment.

Comment: @Ramhound that's what it displays on router's status, btw, it's a TP-LINK tl-wr941nd

Comment: Yes I realize you have 3 antennas but the reason you have 3 antennas isn't for it to support different 802.11 modes.

Comment: As @ramhound intimated, multiple antennas are for MIMO support, not b/g/n support.  If you are going to get to the bottom of yhis you really need to learn about (a) MIMO. (b) Signal to noise ratio and attenuation  (c) signal reflection and amplification and (d) bandwidth frequency characteristics on the supported bands.  You will need to become precise in your descriptions, measurementsvsnd tests.